# Problem to play parallel sound using SoundPool in android Studio piano practice

Tags: java, android, soundpool, audiotrack

I can not play parallel sound using SoundPool and Thread for my piano app.

I want to create a simple 1 octave Piano, the mp3 files are loaded in raw folder, the problem is when I push piano buttons , the new pushed key will cut the previous one sound if not finished yet.
then I put the "last key" in Thread but still same problem.

```
// my simple piano class

public class PianoDraw extends View {
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  final int x = (int) event.getX();
  final int y = (int) event.getY();
  i = -1;
  for (Rect item : whiteArray) {
      i += 1;
       if (item.contains(x, y)) {
          switch (i) {
                  // first key "Do" with no thread to play sound
                   case 0: {
                        soundPool.load(getContext(), R.raw.wk1, 1);
                        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }

                   // I removed 5 other keys to short the code

                   // the last key with Thread
                    case 6: {
                        Thread myTheared = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                soundPool.load(getContext(), R.raw.wk7, 1);
                            }
                        });
                        myTheared.start();
                    }
                }//switch
            }//if
        }//for
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

the sound pool initialed once and will play sound after loading but not parallel

```
    public void initSoundPool() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .build();
            soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                    .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
                    .build();
        } else {
            soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        }
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                soundPool.play(sampleId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Should I use soundTrack or other class ?